# Изменение имени класса/стиля компонента при клике на React компонент

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Есть проект, который с помощью компонентов Patternfly создает меню на React. Элементы меню создаются из массива словарей с конфигурацией. Я хочу при нажатии на отдельный элемент меню менять стиль нижнего контейнера div так чтоб он показывался либо нет.

```
class MenuWithLinks extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        activeItem: 0
      };
      
    }
    onSelect(event, itemId){
        this.setState({
          activeItem: itemId
        });
      }
      
      
    render() {
        
      
      const { activeItem } = this.state;
      const conft =[{addr: 'PC1',id:0,name:'First PC'},{addr: 'PC2',id:1,name:'Second PC'},]
     
      return ( 
        <Menu  activeItemId={activeItem}>
          <MenuContent>
            <MenuList>
            {conft.map(function(links) {return<MenuItem isExternalLink onClick={() => console.log(console.log("clicked"))} itemId={links.id}>{links.name}  <div style={{display: 'block'}}>
            <iframe   src={`http://localhost:4200/DEVICE/${links.addr}/`}  frameBorder="0"> </iframe> SomeVedomosti
               
          </div></MenuItem> },this)}
            </MenuList>
          </MenuContent>
        </Menu>
        
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И так, проблему с изменением видимости я решил.

Элементу, видимость которого мы хотим менять присваиваем некий уникальный айди:

```
<div id={given.Name} style={{display : 'none', height: '100%'}}> </div>
```

Затем объявляем функцию, которая как раз и будет искать наш элемент и менять его стиль.

```
 function changeVisibility(sid) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(sid);
  var typedisp = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).display;
  typedisp = typedisp === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
  elem.style.display = typedisp;
  }
```

Данная функция, как параметр принимает айди нужного элемента.
И после всего у другого элемента на событие onClick() сажаем вызов функции, которая описана выше и передаем айди нужного элемента(в моем случае событие onClick использовалось у компонента PatterFly MenuItem

```
<MenuItem onClick={()=>{changeVisibility(given.Name)}}>
 <div id={given.Name} style={{display : 'none', height: '100%'}}>
</div>
</MenuItem>
```

Если кому надо привожу описание всего компонента:

```
class MenuBasicList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeItem: 0,
     
    };
console.log(this.props.curSw)
this.onSelect = (event, itemId) => {
  console.log(`clicked ${itemId}`);
  this.setState({
    activeItem: itemId
  });
  
};


 }
 
  render() {
    const { activeItem } = this.state;
    const openInNewTab = (url) => {
      const newWindow = window.open(url, '_blank', 'noopener,noreferrer')
      if (newWindow) newWindow.opener = null
    }

function changeVisibility(sid) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(sid);
  var typedisp = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).display;
  typedisp = typedisp === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
  elem.style.display = typedisp;
  
  console.log(window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).display);

}

return (
  <Menu activeItemId={activeItem} onSelect={this.onSelect}>
    <MenuContent>
      <MenuList>
      {
      this.props.prms.map( (given) => {return given.host === this.props.curSw ? ([<MenuItem onClick={()=>{changeVisibility(given.Name)}}>
         <div  style={{display:'flex', alignItems: 'center'}}>
           
         <img src={given.picture ==="router" ? routerpic : given.picture === "switch" ? switchpic : given.picture === "asa" ? asapic : null}  height="45px" width="90px" alt="Some image" /> 
         <p style={{fontSize: '3.5vh', margin: '0.5em'}}>{given.Name}</p>
        </div> 

         <div id={given.Name} style={{display : 'none', height: '100%'}}>
           
           <iframe  src={given.address}  style={{ height: '400px', width : "50%",float: 'left'}} ></iframe>
           
            <ul>
              <li><b>Model</b>: {given.info.model} </li>
              <li><b>RAM size:</b> {given.info.ram}</li>
              <ul style={{listStyle:'square outside', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Modules: {given.info.modules.map((module) => {return <li style={{marginLeft: "54%", fontWeight: 'normal'}}>{module}</li> })}</ul>
              <li><img src={ require('./networks/'+given.info.image).default} width={'50%'} alt="image not found" /></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         </MenuItem>]) : ""})
         }
      </MenuList>
    </MenuContent>
  </Menu>
);


 }
}
```